# ODBC Connection failur in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

When I am trying to create the ODBC connection form my client machine I am getting an error as in the screen shot.

My server machine is 64 bit and my client machine is 32 bit.Will you have any idea[image]

Comment: Will you be able to be more specific? What have you tried, did you googled the error code, do you have your ports opened on the server, can you access the server/ping the server, is your network connection stable...

Comment: I think you need to install updated driver, you can do it by installing sql client on on the client machine

Comment: Yes akluth..I am able to acess the server and able to ping too and also the connection is stable too.Asl the issue occur only for some times.Some time i am able to connect it without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made your server to accept remote connections? 
After a standard installation it is not accepting remote connections, you can change that on the server with the "SQL Server Configuration Manager"

When you open that you will have to enable TCP/IP Client and the TCP Protocol. After that you have to restart the SQL Server service and open port 1433 in your firewall. If it is a standard installation that will do.

You also can look into the sql server properties (through SQL Server Management Server) and then on the connections tab enable remote access.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The way you told me to look helps